# How to create an EC2 instance using AWS APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Today, I started working on AWS. I want to create an EC2 instance by using API only. I want to do more actions like copying instance, creating bucket, transforming file from one instance to another etc.

I am not getting how to create the instance using API.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Which programming language (or SDK) are you hoping to use?

Comment: The API is `RunInstances`. AWS supports multiple programming languages. The documentation for this API can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html. At the bottom are the references for different programming languages.

Comment: @Krishna Kumar R I want to use python.I know little about python. But I didn't get how to trigger the api using python? Can you tell me.

Comment: I am new to aws, how to do this, I am not getting.

Comment: For example,I have this request, how to send this.  response = client.update_instance(
    InstanceId='string',
    LayerIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    InstanceType='string',
    AutoScalingType='load'|'timer',
    Hostname='string',
    Os='string',
    AmiId='string',
    SshKeyName='string',
    Architecture='x86_64'|'i386',
    InstallUpdatesOnBoot=True|False,
    EbsOptimized=True|False,
    AgentVersion='string'
)                how to use this code to update instance

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-launch.html) are some examples using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

> aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxxx

Comment: I got required api's , But didn't get how to trigger those api?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code to create an EC2 instance.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-123456', SubnetId='subnet-12345', InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, KeyName='my-keypair', SecurityGroupIds=['sg-123456'])
```

Modify the image id: `ami-123456`, subnet id: `subnet-12345`, keypair name: `my-keypair` and security group id: `sg-123456`. Save this file as `run_instances.py` (or any name) and execute the script as: `python run_instances.py`. If you have setup your credentials properly, the instance will be launched in us-east-1.

**References**:

- Setting up environment variables: [Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)
- Configure profiles: [Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html)
- Run instances boto3: [boto3 run_instances()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)